# SQL query Inner joins returns multiple rows

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle10g

We have got 2 tables; table1, table2.

> *table1*:
>
> ```
> CNTY | ZIP  | SERVICE
> 111  | 1234 |  N
> 111  |      |  Y 
> 112  |      |  Y
> ```
>
> *table2*:
>
> ```
> CNTY | ZIP  |
> 111  | 1234 |
> 111  | 4321 |
> 112  | 4433 |
> ```

We are using oracle and trying the below query -

```sql
SELECT t1.SERVICE
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.CNTY IN (SELECT t2.CNTY
                     FROM table2 t2
                    WHERE t2.ZIP = '4433')
```

which return Y which is expected behavior. but if we send the `t2.zip='4321'` it is returning 2 rows, but we are expecting one row (Y). Also, if we send `t2.zip='1234'` which should return 'N'. But, above query returns 2 rows.

I am very new database side. We tried, but could not get it in one single statement. Is there any way to get the expected behavior?

Basically what I am expecting from the query is -

1. It should always return the `SERVICE` value from `table1`. If it finds the `ZIP` in `table1` it should return the `SERVICE` value for the matching zip.
2. If there is no matching `ZIP` in `table1`, then it should find the `CNTY` associated with the given zip in `table2` and then taking that `CNTY` value from `table2`, it should find the `SERVICE` value in `table1` for the matching `CNTY` and return the value.

For example: For the ZIP 4321 no matching entry in the table1, but in table2 4321 is associated with 111, so for 111 in table1 SERVICE value is Y. So, the query should return Y.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you expect only one row. Let's examine what the query does:

```
SELECT t2.CNTY FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.ZIP = '4321'
```

This returns a single value: 111, corresponding to the following row:

```
     111  | 4321 |
```

So the complete query is equivalent to

```
SELECT t1.SERVICE FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.CNTY IN (111)
```

And that returns the service of these 2 rows, since they both have their CNTY equal to 111:

```
     111  | 1234 |  N
     111  |      |  Y
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns two becuase you have two rows in table1 with the city 111

```
select t1.* from
table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.city = t1.city and (t2.zip = t1.zip or t2.zip is null)
```

Now you are joinig on both city and zip code or if no zip code.

This will just return one row but if there are two city rows with 111 and no zip code then it will return 2

(note: not tested this SQL - Ive done it from memory ;) )

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get the expected behavior?

Yes, you could join the tables on both `CNTY` and `ZIP`.

```
SELECT t1.SERVICE
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
 WHERE t1.CNTY = t2.CNTY AND t1.ZIP = t2.ZIP
   AND t2.ZIP = '1234'
```

However, the above still won't work for ZIP '4321'. For this, the join must be more complicated.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1a.SERVICE, t1b.SERVICE) AS SERVICE
  FROM table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1a ON t1a.CNTY = t2.CNTY AND t1a.ZIP = t2.ZIP
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1b ON t1b.CNTY = t2.CNTY AND COALESCE(t1b.ZIP, '') = ''
  WHERE t2.ZIP = '4321'
```

This second query will work for all cases.

Comment: Above query will not work , because ` t1.ZIP = t2.ZIP` will fail as t1.zip is empty and t2.zip is 4321 right ?

Comment: I understand now, thank you for clarifying. See my new answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But, for some reason, even the new query will not return 'Y' for 4321. Instead it returns empty/null.( What I am expecting here is,-  1. It should always return the value from table1. If it finds the zip in table1 it should return the service value for the matching zip. 2. If there is no matching zip in table1, then it should find the CNTY associated with the given zip in table2 and then taking CNTY value from table2, it should find the service value in table1 for the matching CNTY and return the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select service from (
  select row_number() over (order by t1.zip nulls last) rn, service 
    from table1 t1 
      join table2 t2 on t2.cnty = t1.cnty and (t2.zip = t1.zip or t1.zip is null) 
    where coalesce(t1.zip, t2.zip) = '1234')
  where rn=1
```

`row_number` used to sort records if there are two rows from `join`, like for zip=1234.
Query worked correctly for every zip.

You can also use:

```
  select 
      case 
        when exists (select 1 from table1 where zip='1234') 
        then 
          (select service from table1 where zip='1234')
        else
          (select service from table1 where zip is null 
              and cnty = (select cnty from table2 where zip='1234')) 
    end service
    from dual
```

like here:

```
  with zips as (select '1234' zip from dual 
    union select '4321' from dual 
    union select '4433' from dual 
    union select 'TEST' from dual)
  select zips.zip, 
      case 
        when exists (select 1 from table1 where zip=zips.zip) 
        then 
          (select service from table1 where zip=zips.zip)
        else
          (select service from table1 where zip is null and cnty = 
             (select cnty from table2 where zip=zips.zip)) 
      end service
    from zips

zip     service
1234    N
4321    Y
4433    Y
TEST    null
```